# Cassandra cluster и точка входа для клиента

Tags: cluster, nosql, cassandra

Решил почитать про noSQL Cassandra, вроде все понятно, все интересно, НО, возник вопрос про доступ к кластеру.

Например, есть у меня кластер из нескольких нод. Все хорошо, реплицируется, но какую точку входа использовать? например я буду использвоать для подключения ноду 0 с адресом 192.168.0.1. Если вдруг по какойто причине она будет недоступна, то я могу использовать вторую ноду (нода 1) с адресом 192.168.0.2.
Вопрос состоит в том что как это сделать прозрачно для работы, в плане того, что я (читай разработчик) не должен "пинговать" ноды на предмет их доступности. Я вижу только чтото типа DNS RoundRobin, однако это добавляет туже проблему, что если одна нода недоступна, то мне нужно все равно еще раз подключаться к  ноде по доменому имени? ЗалУпить попытки подключения пока оно не будет установлено? Вообще как это реализуется в продакшене?

---

Хотя наверное это не только к cassandra относится :)

---

после просмотра исходников все встало на свои места, при подключении указываются все ноды кластера и библиотека сама все пингует и подключается. Так что вопрос неактуален стал. :) Посыпаю голову пеплом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А как вы еще собираетесь определять отпавшие ноды или ноды с большой латентностью? Ребята из Netflix ,например, написали свой Java-клиент для Cassandra - [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax) с failover, пулом соединений, мониторингом и прочими плюшками. Используйте или изучайте, как именно они организовали доступ к Cassandra-кластеру.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.  
Но я имел ввиду несколько другое, имелось ввиду что ноды "пигуются" вручную) Однако после просмотра исходников все встало на свои места, при подключении указываются все ноды кластера и библиотека сама все пингует и подключается.

Comment: Подскажите, где в настройках прописать и настроить кластер с нодами?